# How to set location.state of history object in props in jest/enzyme testing of react component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-redux

In development mode, data is passed using location.state through parent component to EditHandler component i.e,

```
this.props.history.push(`/channels/${id}`, { handler: selectedHandler});
```

In the EditHandler component data from location.state is taken and set in componentWillMount() using the following code

```
const state = this.state;
const handler = this.props.location.state.handler;
state.handler = handler;
this.setState({ ...state });
```

In testing using enzyme, how to set location.state during mount?

Tried to set using props but showing state undefined...

```
       var props: any = {};
       var handler={declared here};

       test('testing here',()=>{
       props.history.location.state({ handler: handler })
       let wrapper = mount(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <EditHandler {...props} history={history} />
            </Provider>
        </BrowserRouter>,
    ); 
     console.log(wrapper.debug());
    })
```

checked using console.log(wrapper.debug()) and found state is undefined in history.location

Tell method to set state in history in testing!

Comment: found the solution here:https://dev.to/wolverineks/react-router-testing-location-state-33fo
thanks!